# Assistance need it

Tags: excel, vba

Sub or function is not defined:
why and how to resolve it?

```
Sub FormulaSravnenie()

'order: F=Pal, G=Lay, H = Kar, I= SPCB, J=Quantity
'order2: L=pal, M=lay, N=box, O=subbov,P=pcs

If (j2 > f2) Then L2 = RoundDown(j2 / L2)
Else: L2 = 0
End
If (j2 > f2) Then m2 = RoundDown((j2 - f2) / g2)
ElseIf (j2 < f2 And j2 > g2) Then m2 = RoundDown(j2 / g2)
Else: m2 = 0
End
If (j2 > f2) Then n2 = RoundDown((j2 - (f2 + g2)) / h2)
ElseIf (j2 < f2 And j2 > g2) Then n2 = RoundDown(j2 - g2) / h2
ElseIf (j2 < g2 And j2 > h2) Then n2 = RoundDown(j2 / h2)
Else: n2 = 0
End
If (j2 > f2) Then o2 = RoundDown((j2 - (f2 + g2 + h2) / i2))
ElseIf (j2 < f2 And j2 > g2) Then o2 = RoundDown(j2 - (g2 + h2) / i2)
ElseIf (j2 < g2 And j2 > h2) Then o2 = RoundDown(j2 - h2) / i2
ElseIf (j2 < h2 And j2 > i2) Then o2 = RoundDown(j2 / i2)
Else: o2 = 0
End
If (j2 > 0) Then p2 = j2 - (f2 + g2 + h2 + i2)
Else: p2 = 0

End

End Sub
```

[IMG]http://i60.tinypic.com/hrzs6h.jpg[/IMG]

so I want from the data F to J row to use this formulas and have the results in L to P row.

```
If (j2 > f2) Then L2 = RoundDown(j2 / L2)
Else: L2 = 0
End
```

'result in L
and so on for the next rows and formulas

Comment: Probably RoudDown does not exist ? Also you should "close" `If` with and `End If` and learn about `indentation`. Your code is horrible to read.

Answer (score 0):

Excel doesn't know RoundDown, you could use '\' instead of '/' to get the Integer rounded down. And you let the sub end directly after the second if.
If you just remove the 'end's it is accessing the whole code. I hope that can help you.

```
    Sub FormulaSravnenie()

'podredba koloni: F=Pal, G=Lay, H = Kar, I= SPCB, J=Quantity
'podredba 2 formula: L=pal, M=lay, N=box, O=subbov,P=pcs


If (j2 > f2) Then L2 = (j2 \ L2)

If (j2 <= f2) Then L2 = 0

If (j2 > f2) Then m2 = ((j2 - f2) \ g2)
If (j2 < f2 And j2 > g2) Then m2 = (j2 \ g2)
If (j2 < g2) Then m2 = 0
If (j2 > f2) Then n2 = ((j2 - (f2 + g2)) \ h2)
If (j2 < f2 And j2 > g2) Then n2 = (j2 - g2) \ h2
If (j2 < g2 And j2 > h2) Then n2 = (j2 \ h2)
If (j2 < h2) Then n2 = 0
If (j2 > f2) Then o2 = ((j2 - (f2 + g2 + h2) \ i2))
If (j2 < f2 And j2 > g2) Then o2 = (j2 - (g2 + h2) \ i2)
If (j2 < g2 And j2 > h2) Then o2 = (j2 - h2) \ i2
If (j2 < h2 And j2 > i2) Then o2 = (j2 \ i2)
If (j2 < i2) Then o2 = 0
If (j2 > 0) Then p2 = j2 - (f2 + g2 + h2 + i2)
If (j2 <= 0) Then p2 = 0

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to use `Application.WorksheetFunction.RoundDown`

VBA doesn't have a native function called RoundDown

e.g.

```
If (j2 > f2) Then L2 = Application.WorksheetFunction.RoundDown(j2 / L2, 2) 
'The function expects a value (your calculation) and the no. of digits after comma
Else: L2 = 0
End
```